# FabricJS Textbox - The cursor position is not set correctly for certain fonts

Tags: fabricjs

[image]

In the above image, the cursor should be at the end, but for some reason, it is placed before the last character.
This only happens for certain fonts.

I don't think it is related with how the custom font is being loaded, this image was taken from http://fabricjs.com/loadfonts. Also, the last version of the library is being used.

To reproduce the issue you have to do the following:

1. Change the font-family to "Pacifico".
2. Click on the text box to enter in edit mode.
3. Start typing.

Sometimes, even the last character goes outside of the bounding box.
I think that this has something to do with how the _measureChar() function executes, but I'm not sure what needs to be changed.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
I did more tests and it seems that this problem is not present in IE.
This problem appears in Chrome and Firefox.
It is also strange how the characters are being rendered in each browser:
[image]

Comment: pacifico has some weird kerning, may be some wrong measurement

Comment: yes, I think this may be the reason. I've also noticed that in IE the problem doesn't seem to appear. Also, the shape of each character doesn't seem to be consistent across browsers. I've updated my question by adding an image to show this.

Comment: I think that this issue may be related to https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/3588

Comment: That issue is cleared much time ago. most of text code from 1.7 do not apply to 2.x

Answer (score 3):

add below code before canvas.requestRenderAll();

```
fabric.charWidthsCache[this.value] = {};
canvas.getActiveObject()._initDimensions();
canvas.getActiveObject().setCoords();
```

Comment: I added this code in the onInput() method, right before requestRenderAll() is called, but the cursor position is still not being set correctly.

Comment: plz add jsfiddle so i will try there

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f1v3/f12841gc/   The problem is not present if you select "Times New Roman". I've created a Textbox subclass to modify the onInput() function by including the code that you specified