# Fix cursor for font fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, cursor-position

I have a font... the circle monogram. The cursor for it does not want to line up with the actual position of the character insertion... Note the position of the cursor after the first character is typed, and the size of the textbox.

[image]

Note the position of the cursor after the second character is typed, and the size of the textbox.

[image]

Note the position after the third character is typed, and the size of the textbox.

[image]

So... hopefully these images are enough to understand what I am trying to accomplish, but if not then basically I am trying to programmatically move the cursor into the right location... If you couldn't tell... there will always be three letters max. This thread [FabricJS Textbox - The cursor position is not set correctly for certain fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47461935/fabricjs-textbox-the-cursor-position-is-not-set-correctly-for-certain-fonts) is what I want, but it doesn't look like anything was actually fixed. Thank you in advance.

Edit: This is related to the bounding box of text, seeing that it doesn't use the most accurate means of computing kerning and what not. Read the comments under this post.

Comment: Did you load the font using FontFaceObserver?

Comment: Just now being able to get around to this... It was exam week this week and last week I had a group project. Unfortunately, adding a font face observer to load the font hasn't worked.

Comment: By the time this was posted, the lib was on version 3, fabricJS is now on version 5 and V6 is out in beta. If it is still causing problems, a reproduction of some sort would be needed to help.

Comment: @Salketer this is true, but this is %100 related to the library's ability to read font information properly. There are open issues for this on their git. Version 5 (and 6 at the moment) won't fix this. They're likely going to have to include opentype.js to resolve font related issues, but at the moment, there would be a lot to rework. It's not hard to find threads that are reproducible, so I'm in favor of closing this. Here are some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68816467/3155240, https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/2552,
https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/1326